# If $p>q>1$, then prove that $p^n-q^n>n(p-q)$ for all positive integer $n\geq 2$

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** If $p>q>1$, then prove that $p^n-q^n>n(p-q)$ for all positive integer $n\geq 2$.

**My effort:** For any positive integer $n$ we have,
$p^n-q^n=(p-q)(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}q+p^{n-3}q^2+\dots +q^{n-1})$.
$\implies \frac{p_n-q^n}{p-q}=(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}q+p^{n-2}q^2+\dots +q^{n-1})\geq 1+1+1\dots+1=n$.

Comment: In the second factor , all terms are seperated with "$+$" , there is no alternating sum. The claim is therefore quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a mistake in your factorization:

We have $$p^{n} - q^{n} = (p-q)(p^{n-1} + p^{n-2}q + p^{n-3}q^{2} + \cdots + q^{n-1}),$$ with all addition signs instead of alternating addition and subtraction signs.

To see this, note that $$p(p^{n-1} + p^{n-2}q + p^{n-3}q^{2} + \cdots + q^{n-1}) = p^{n} + p^{n-1}q +  p^{n-2}q^{2} \cdots + pq^{n-1},$$
and
$$q(p^{n-1} + p^{n-2}q + p^{n-3}q^{2} + \cdots + q^{n-1}) = p^{n-1}q + p^{n-2}q^{2} + p^{n-3}q^{3} +  \cdots + q^{n}.$$

Clearly, when you subtract the second from the first, you get $p^{n} - q^{n},$ as expected.

Once you have this factorization, it shouldn't be too hard to carry the rest of the argument out.